# Potential problems of mapping JSON to XML

Tags: json, xml

What are the major problems of mapping JSON to XML and viceversa? I have a set of problems that I can run into, but it would be very helpful if others can add what they have ran into when converting between both.

My list is:

- Root object required in JSON
- Unique keys (although only one of the two specifications requires this)
- Keys cannot start with a number
- Order may not be preserved (see http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html)
- Any other one?

Comment: Valid XML document should have a root object as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix), a XML<->JSON conversion library written in JavaScript. So I'm speaking a bit from experience of mapping between complex XML and JSON.

- Top-level production in JSON may be `JSONArray` or `JSONObject` (in JSON interchange format even any `JSONText` - also null, boolean, string, number). XML requires a single root element.
- JSON objects have properties, XML elements may have attributes, contain sub-elements and text values (I'm even leaving comments and PIs out).
- You're mentioning "keys cannot start with a number", but there's more syntactical incompatibilities. JSON object properties can be basically any strings. XML element and attribute names are restricted in syntax.
- Normally no namespaces in JSON, often namespaces in XML.
- Strict typing. You always know JSON type just by looking at the value. In XML, you can't guess type from the value. For instance `1` may be string, boolean, a dozen of numeric types etc. You have to know the schema to know types.
- In JSON, you can guess the structure from value (object or array). In XML, if you see an single element, you don't know if it may be repeated or not. You have to know the schema to know the structure.
- Collections are normally expressed as arrays in JSON. In XML, you can express a collection as repeatable elements (`item*`), possibly wrapped (`items/item*`), or in case of simple types as list types (`<items>a b c d</items>`).
- In XML, the order of sub-elements or text nodes of the element is significant. In JSON, properties of the `JSONObject` are not ordered. (You mention this.)
- In XML, an element may contain several sub-elements of the same name. In `JSONObject`, property names will be unique. (You mention this.)
- In XML, an element may contain attributes, sub-elements and text nodes. In JSON, the only complex structures are `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`. In `JSONArray` you just have items, no named components (which would be analogous to attributes or sub-elements). In `JSONObject` you just have properties (`JSONMembers`) which are always "named" (this would be analogous to attributes and sub-elements of XML, but not to text nodes).
- Processing instructions and comments in XML, no direct analogs in JSON.
- There's also `xsi:type` construct which is a bit hard to handle. Specifies the type of the element value in the document instance.
- In XML, values of certain types (like `QName`s) depend on the declarations in other parts of the XML document. For example, having `my:Element` as `xs:QName`-value somewhere, this value will depend on how the `my` namespace prefix is declared in the document. Since namespaces may be declared and re-declared, you have to follow their declaraition quite precisely to be able to find out the namespace of the qualified name.

Comment: Thank you very much lexicore, extremely useful!

Answer (score 1):

Converting a specific JSON object (or class of objects) into XML is usually no problem at all. What is difficult is writing a converter that can handle *any* JSON object. The problem essentially arises because you want simple JSON to end up as simple XML, but you find yourself contorting the design to handle edge cases, such as characters that are legal in JSON but not in XML, preserving distinctions such as the distinction between the number 10 and the string "10", or worrying about the best representation of a JSON "null".